# Sum Values for multiple unique field values

Tags: arcpy, cursor, table

I am trying to modify an existing table that I can relate to a feature in Arcmap(v10.5).

Currently, the table fields and values look like this:
[image: Sample data table]

I would like to summarize the table.  For each unique "property number" value, I would like to have the table list unique "fagtype" values.  And for each "fagtype value", I would like the table to sum the "fagacres" for each value.  I would like the "facres" and "fagirrig" fields to just list unique values as well.

I found a starting place under the "search cursor" summary on the ESRI help page.  But it's a very limited start and I'm not sure where to go from here, or even if a searchcursor is the best route.

```py
import arcpy

agtable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

fields = ['PID', 'fagtype', 'fagacres', 'facres', 'fagirrig']


with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(agtable, fields) as cursor:

    for row in cursor:
```

Comment: I'd take a look at [Summary Stats](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm). If you want to use search cursors, take a look at [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: Looks like the default dictionaries are the way to go.

Comment: Did you try using SQL? It looks to me like a group by and a sum would do wonders.

Comment: I'm very limited in SQL knowledge.  However, I do know what your talking about.  And that probably is the best way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a simple job for [Summary Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm). But if you want to use python, pandas is a great module for tasks like this and is included in ArcGIS 10.5:

> pandas is an open source, BSD-licensed library providing
>   high-performance, easy-to-use data structures and data analysis tools
>   for the Python programming language.

You can create a pandas dataframe from a feature class table using the da.SearchCursor and then groupby and sum:

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd

feature_class = r'C:\database.gdb\feature_class' #Change
fc_fields = ['Property_number','fagtype','fagacres','facres'] #Change

#Function to read a feature class and return a pandas dataframe
def fc_to_dataframe(fc, fields):
    cursor = (i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=cursor, columns=fields)
    return df

#Call function
df = fc_to_dataframe(feature_class, fc_fields)

#Group and sum
print df.groupby(['Property_number','fagtype']).sum()
```

Comment: +1 Pandas is amazing. You can read directly from the cursor if you use `pd.DataFrame.from_records(arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields), columns=fields)` No need to wrap in another generator.

Comment: Nice did not know that